# First Person view of structures in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

```
(* code to Construct structures *)

wing = {
(*Base Cylinders*)
 {Gray, Cylinder[{{10, 10, 10}, {10, 10, 6}}, 7]},
 {Blue, Cylinder[{{10, 10, 6}, {10, 10, 5}}, 7]},
 {Blue, Cylinder[{{10, 10, 5}, {10, 10, 4}}, 7]},
 {Gray, Cylinder[{{10, 10, 4}, {10, 10, 2}}, 7]},

 (*top cylinders*)
 {Blue, Cylinder[{{10, 10, 12}, {10, 10, 10}}, 4]},
 {Gray, Cylinder[{{10, 10, 14}, {10, 10, 12}}, 4]},

 (*Parallel Beamers*)
 {Gray, Cuboid[{0, 7, 12}, {20, 13, 2}]}};

  house = {
  (*the house*)
  {Darker[Red, 0.3], Cuboid[{-10, -10, 0}, {2, 3, 12}]},

   (*roof*)
   {Darker[Brown, 0.4], 
   Polygon[{{-10, -10, 12}, {-4, -3, 18}, {2, -10, 12}}]},
   {Darker[Brown, 0.4], 
   Polygon[{{2, -10, 12}, {-4, -3, 18}, {2, 3, 12}}]},
   {Darker[Brown, 0.4], 
   Polygon[{{2, 3, 12}, {-4, -3, 18}, {-10, 3, 12}}]},
   {Darker[Brown, 0.4], 
    Polygon[{{-10, 3, 12}, {-4, -3, 18}, {-10, -10, 12}}]},

    (*Door*)
   {Yellow, 
   Polygon[{{2.005, -5.25, 0}, {2.005, -5.25, 5}, {2.005, -1.75, 
   5}, {2.005, -1.75, 0}}]},
   (*Door Knob*)
   {Orange, Sphere[{2.005, -2.25, 2.5}, 0.25]},
   (*Windows*)
   {Lighter[Blue, 0.5], 
   Polygon[{{2.005, -9, 6}, {2.005, -9, 10}, {2.005, -5, 
   10}, {2.005, -5, 6}}]}, {Lighter[Blue, 0.5], 
   Polygon[{{2.005, -1.75, 6}, {2.005, -1.75, 10}, {2.005, 2, 
   10}, {2.005, 2, 6}}]},

   (*Chimney*)
   {Gray, Cuboid[{-2, -9, 12.75}, {-5, -7, 17}]},

   (*Lines for the Window*)
   {Black, Cuboid[{2.006, -9, 7.9}, {2.006, -5, 8.1}]},
   {Black, Cuboid[{2.006, -7.1, 6}, {2.006, -6.9, 10}]},
   {Black, Cuboid[{2.006, 0, 6}, {2.006, 0.2, 10}]},
   {Black, Cuboid[{2.006, -1.75, 7.9}, {2.006, 2, 8.1}]},

   (*Lawn*)
   {Darker[Green, 0.5], 
    Polygon[{{2, -10, 0}, {2, 3, 0}, {-10, 3, 0}, {-10, 10, 0}, {2, 
    10, 0}, {10, 10, 0}, {10, -10, 0}}]},

   (*Pavement*)
   {Darker[Gray, 0.5], 
   Polygon[{{2, -5.25, 0.005}, {2, -1.75, 0.005}, {10, -1.75, 
   0.005}, {10, -5.25, 0.005}}]},
   (*Side Windows*)
   {Lighter[Blue, 0.5], 
   Polygon[{{1, 3.005, 2}, {1, 3.005, 5}, {-4, 3.005, 5}, {-4, 3.005,
    2}}]}, {Lighter[Blue, 0.5], 
   Polygon[{{-5, 3.005, 7}, {-9, 3.005, 7}, {-9, 3.005, 10}, {-5, 
   3.005, 10}}]}, {Lighter[Blue, 0.5], 
   Polygon[{{0, 3.005, 7}, {0, 3.005, 11}, {-2, 3.005, 11}, {-2, 
   3.005, 7}}]}, {Lighter[Blue, 0.5], 
   Polygon[{{-6, 3.005, 2}, {-6, 3.005, 6}, {-8, 3.005, 6}, {-8, 
   3.005, 2}}]}, {Lighter[Blue, 0.5], 
   Polygon[{{1, -10.005, 2}, {1, -10.005, 5}, {-4, -10.005, 
   5}, {-4, -10.005, 2}}]}, {Lighter[Blue, 0.5], 
   Polygon[{{-5, -10.005, 7}, {-9, -10.005, 7}, {-9, -10.005, 
   10}, {-5, -10.005, 10}}]}, {Lighter[Blue, 0.5], 
   Polygon[{{0, -10.005, 7}, {0, -10.005, 11}, {-2, -10.005, 
   11}, {-2, -10.005, 7}}]}, {Lighter[Blue, 0.5], 
   Polygon[{{-6, -10.005, 2}, {-6, -10.005, 6}, {-8, -10.005, 
   6}, {-8, -10.005, 2}}]},


   (*Back Window*)
   {Lighter[Blue, 0.5], 
   Polygon[{{-10.005, 1, 3}, {-10.005, 1, 9}, {-10.005, -8, 
   9}, {-10.005, -8, 3}}]},

    (*Lines for the Window*)
   {Black, Cuboid[{-1.4, 3.006, 2}, {-1.6, 3.006, 5}]},
   {Black, Cuboid[{1, 3.006, 3.4}, {-4, 3.005, 3.6}]},
   {Black, Cuboid[{-6.85, 3.006, 7}, {-7.1, 3.006, 10}]},
   {Black, Cuboid[{-5, 3.006, 8.4}, {-9, 3.006, 8.6}]},
   {Black, Cuboid[{-1.4, -10.006, 2}, {-1.6, -10.006, 5}]},
   {Black, Cuboid[{1, -10.006, 3.4}, {-4, -10.005, 3.6}]},
   {Black, Cuboid[{-6.85, -10.006, 7}, {-7.1, -10.006, 10}]},
   {Black, Cuboid[{-5, -10.006, 8.4}, {-9, -10.006, 8.6}]}};

    (* Holds the constructions together *)

  tab = HoldForm@{
  place[wing, 2, {0, 70, -27}, 0, "Building1"],
  place[house, 1, {170, 200, -50}, 0, "Building2"]};

    (* defining the function place in the above function *)

   place[obj_, scale_, trans_, rotate_, name_] := 
   GeometricTransformation[obj, 
   ScalingTransform[scale {1, 1, 1}].TranslationTransform[
   trans].RotationTransform[rotate Degree, {0, 0, 1}]]

   (* Function to show the images in a particular plane *)

    view := Show[
    Graphics3D[ReleaseHold[tab], PlotRange -> Automatic, 
     ImageSize -> {500, 500}, Boxed -> True, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, Axes -> True]];




    (*--------------code over ----------------------------------------------------*)
```

The above code when evaluated gives us the following images

[image: X axis view]
[image: Side View]
[image: Top view]

I want to have first person view of these image in the plane. I want to able to move around the the plane with the images as structures and have a chance to move like they are original views

Is there a way that can be done. Can we have a object that can be moved on the x-axis that allows to move around the x axis and could allow us to see the structures where the x axis and y axis and z axis, can be changed by the parameters?

Comment: I think you want the `ViewPoint` option. By the way, there is now a Mathematica-specific StackExchange: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Comment: By the way, the code you posted only seems to include the little house, which is sufficient. Also, it's not a good idea to "format" the code with MarkDown. I had to clean it up before it would work on my Mathematica installation.

Comment: You can do some ad hoc zooming around by using alt-left-click-mouse-movement (in/out), alt-shift-left-click-mouse-movement (rotations), and shift-left-click-mouse-movement (up/down/left/right). But it is not possible to shift the POV inside the plot.

Comment: the ad hoc zooming thing works but , but i wish to have like a camera view of the entire plane on which the structures are placed . check this video on youtube : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RipJuvbF5xI in this video he shows like a camera zoom in a structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3538/46) might help you to better understand concepts like `ViewVector` and `ViewAngle`. The code below lets you experiment a bit with how the position of the camera and the view angle affect the view in your particular example. The code for `tab` is as in the original question.

```
With[{xrange = {0, 180}, yrange = {150, 240}, zrange = {-50, 0}},
 Manipulate[
  DynamicModule[{vv, crd},
   With[{gr = Graphics3D[ReleaseHold[tab], 
       PlotRange -> {xrange, yrange, zrange}, ImageSize -> {500, 500},
       Boxed -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, Axes -> True], eyelevel = -48},

    crd = {Cos[phi] Sin[theta], Sin[theta] Sin[phi], Cos[theta]};
    vv = {Append[{ptx, pty}, eyelevel], Append[{ptx, pty}, eyelevel] + crd};

    Grid[{{Show[{gr,
         Graphics3D[{{Red, Sphere[vv[[1]], .5]},
           {Opacity[.3], Cone[{vv[[1]] + 100 crd, vv[[1]]}, 100 Tan[a/2]]}}]}, 
        ImageSize -> 350],
       Show[gr, Axes -> False, ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}, 
        ViewVector -> vv, ViewAngle -> a , ImageSize -> 350]}}]]],
  {{a, 50 Degree, "View Angle"}, 10 Degree, 180 Degree},
  {{ptx, 100, "Camera Position x"}, Sequence @@ xrange},
  {{pty, 200, "Camera Position y"}, Sequence @@ yrange},
  {{phi, Pi, "Horizontal Angle"}, 0, 2 Pi},
  {{theta, Pi/2, "Vertical Angle"}, 0, Pi}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The image on the left shows an bird's eye view of the buildings where the red dot is the location of the camera and the cone the field of view.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
Manipulate[
 Show[Graphics3D[ReleaseHold[tab], PlotRange -> Automatic, 
   ImageSize -> {500, 500}, Boxed -> True, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, Axes -> True, 
   ViewPoint -> {x, y, z}]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for you Help .. This looks Good , however what i really wanted to achieve is a camera like view to view the structures inside .I have come across a few videos in Youtube and they seem to look awesome , however i was unable to achieve anything close to that

Comment: how can i use ViewAngle and ViewVector on the Manipulate to make it more camera like while moving around .